# Extensions can't be installed?

Tags: visual-studio-code

All extensions have been removed unexpectedly, and cannot re-install. Uninstall and reinstall of VS code with same result:

```
2023-02-24 09:04:21.231 [info] Electron sandbox mode is enabled!
2023-02-24 09:04:21.251 [warning] Via 'product.json#extensionEnabledApiProposals' extension 'github.vscode-pull-request-github' wants API proposal 'commentsResolvedState' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST. Likely, the proposal has been finalized (check 'vscode.d.ts') or was abandoned.
2023-02-24 09:04:21.468 [error] Error scanning installed extensions:
2023-02-24 09:04:21.468 [error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 20641
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/286937/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:741:99212)
2023-02-24 09:04:22.026 [error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 20641
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/286937/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:93520)
2023-02-24 09:04:22.039 [error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 20641
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/286937/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:93520)
2023-02-24 09:04:22.155 [error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 20641
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/286937/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:93520)
2023-02-24 09:04:22.231 [error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 20641
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/286937/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:93520)
2023-02-24 09:04:22.268 [error] Unexpected token a in JSON at position 20641: SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 20641
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/286937/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:93520)
2023-02-24 09:04:23.937 [error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 20641
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/286937/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:93520)
2023-02-24 09:04:23.952 [error] Unexpected token a in JSON at position 20641: SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 20641
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/286937/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:93520)
2023-02-24 09:04:24.224 [info] [perf] Render performance baseline is 34ms
```

Uninstall and re-installed VScode; expecting errors to clear up. A manual download of an extension yields the following:

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Request was blocked due to exceeding usage of resource 'Count' in namespace 'AnonymousId'. For more information on why your request was blocked, see the topic \"Rate limits\" on the Microsoft Web site (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=823950).","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.RequestBlockedException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server","typeKey":"RequestBlockedException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```